# Cannot find the webelement using ID within <ui> or execute javascript onClick

Tags: selenium-webdriver

USE: wEBDRIVER version selenium-2.44.0

Environment: Windows 7 Prof

USE: Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627

LANGUAGE: java  - version: '1.7.0_71'

```
<ul class="tree-default">
  <li class="open" rel="package" id="package_15245" depth="1">
    <a onclick="getLearningPackageInfo(15245);" id="packageNodeName_15245" style="background-image:url(/suite/images/folder2.gif);" href="#">Unit 1</a>
    <ul id="parent_15245" style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li class="open" rel="package" id="package_15402" depth="2">
        <a onclick="getLearningPackageInfo(15402);" id="packageNodeName_15402" style="background-image:url(/suite/images/folder2.gif);" href="#">
          <div class="nonTitleDivs">Lesson 1</div>
          <div class="titleDivs" style="display:none;">Lesson 1: Understanding Simple Graphs</div>
        </a>
    <ul id="parent_15402">
      <li class="leaf" rel="page" id="page_36934" depth="2">
        <a class="clicked" id="pageNodeName_36934" style="background-image:url(/suite/images/text.gif);" onclick="getPageContentAreas(36934, 15402);" href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf" rel="page" id="page_36938" depth="2">
        <a id="pageNodeName_36938" style="background-image:url(/suite/images/text.gif);" onclick="getPageContentAreas(36938, 15402);" href="#">Page 2</a>
```

driver =  new FirefoxDriver();

Executing the following statements:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(59, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("pageNodeName_36938")).click();  // failed here - see error messages below
```

> ERROR MESSAGES:
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"pageNodeName_36938"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 59.14 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
>   System info: host: 'LT-JRCHEN', ip: '10.128.253.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
>   Session ID: ca3454c1-81c8-48ba-b83c-9e058af768cc
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Executing the following statements: using onClick event

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(59, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("getPageContentAreas(36938, 15402)");  // failed here also - see error messages below
```

> ERROR MESSAGES:
>   getPageContentAreas is not defined
>   Command duration or timeout: 71 milliseconds

Any ideas?

Thanks.
jiale

Comment: Please format the code correctly. Help is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and provide necessary html to understand the situation

Comment: Please check whether the element is under a frame or not...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that ID you are using `id("pageNodeName_36938")` is not dynamic?

Looks like this number '36938' will change every time, thats why you are getting NoSuchElementException

You need to find better locator than just ID

Try using xpath locator -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Page 2'])).click();
```